# Solving Isosceles Triangle with all angles and perimeter

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I know that you need at least one side to solve an isosceles triangle given the angles but is it possible to determine the side lengths of an isosceles triangle given the perimeter and all angles?

Comment: Yes, it is. Note that $P=2b+a$,where $P$ is the perimeter and  $a^2=2b^2(1-\cos B)$, where $B$ is the unequal angle of the isosceles triangle, and $a,b,b$ are the sides of the isosceles triangle.

Comment: Sure.  given the angles you know the proportional side lengths (via law of sins) so just find the scaling factor that fits to the perimeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$${a \over \sin A} = {b \over \sin B} \Rightarrow {a} = {b *  \sin A \over \sin B}$$

$$ 2b  + a = P \Rightarrow  2b  + {b *  \sin A \over \sin B} = P$$